# Angular change template element based on the radio button

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-template, angularjs-ng-if

I have two `radio buttons` in my template. on selecting a button, different `input` text fields should be displayed for each `button` and the other fields should hide.

**How can I do this using `Angular`?**

I have tried using `*ngIf` and `ngModel`, but not able to solve this problem.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

> Take a look:

[Source Code, StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/on-clicking-a-radio-button-change-of-input-text-fields-in-angul)

[Demo](https://on-clicking-a-radio-button-change-of-input-text-fields-in-angul.stackblitz.io)

> HTML

```
Type 1: <input type="radio" name="foo" value="type_1" [(ngModel)]="radioBtn">

<br>

Type 2: <input type="radio" name="foo"
 [(ngModel)]="radioBtn" value="type_2">

<br>

<ng-container *ngIf="radioBtn == 'type_1'">
    Type 1: <input type="text" placeholder="Type 1">
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="radioBtn == 'type_2'">
    Type 2: <input type="text" placeholder="Type 2">
</ng-container>
```

> TS

```
export class AppComponent  {
  radioBtn: string = 'type_1';
}
```

> Explanation:

To make radio buttons work, you need two things:

1. You need to set the same name to all the radio buttons belonging together `name="foo"`
2. You need to specify the value for each of those radio buttons`value="bar"`